# Can i generate Doc id from flutter to firebase without the method add?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Uuid.v4 but when im fetching the data it come back as null.
I found out that to fetch the docs id I need to generate id's like : bIEUVI7MQtfWFJYU99yO
is there any way to generate id like this from flutter?

Answer (score 7):

Just create a reference of an empty document like this, it will generate automatically your document ID:

```dart
final documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').doc();

final docId = documentReference.id;
```

Comment: Note that you can use any collection ID, e.g. `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('_').doc();`. The generated doc ID isn't linked to any specific collection.

Comment: Didn't knew this one @RenaudTarnec thanks for mentioning it